# How do you remove MariaDB and NGINX from Mac via terminal?

Tags: mac, apache

How do you remove MariaDB and NGINX from Mac via terminal?

I am just trying to run Apache2 on localhost:8080 but I get the NGINX welcome page.

Comment: Please make your description more specific about how the packages are installed.

Answer (score 1):

Trying stopping the process - `nginx -s stop` should shut the server down. To restart it,  run `which nginx` to tell you where it's running from. Then run the main executable.

Instead of going for the nuclear option of removing it straight away, stop the server. Once you know where it's starting from, you can navigate there and look at the config files to see what port it's on etc. Or you could just nuke it using `rm -rf` on the nginx paths.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you installed them.

For future use, I'd use [homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew) to install everything and then uninstall is done with `brew uninstall`. Homebrew has become a huge open source project with both individual and corporate support.

Actually, I can't easily find any way to install Nginx or MariaDB on macOS without using homebrew. So maybe `brew uninstall nginx` is your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had identical problem, however because I installed nginx after I installed apache2 it was showing the old welcome page despite using correct server.